# Compile c++ code in R does not work anymore

Tags: c++, r, macos, gcc, osx-mavericks

I start saying that i am a newbie in programming and then i am not sure i will be able to explain well my problem.

I had some c++ code i wrote, this code are loaded and used by some R functions.

To compile the code i used the following:

```
R  CMD SHLIB   MyCode.cpp
```

and i loaded the library in R with

```
dyn.load("MyCOde.so")
```

Sometimes i built also an R package and i was able to load it into R.

If i do all these stuff on a Mac with mountain lion everything work fine, but now that i switched to mavericks, i have some problems. The `R  CMD SHLIB   MyCode.cpp` command works but when i used `dyn.load("MyCOde.so")` i get the following text:

```
Errore in dyn.load(paste(dir_function, "MyCOde.so", sep = "")) : 
  unable to load shared object 'MyCOde.so':
  dlopen(MyCOde.so, 6): Symbol not found: __ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev
  Referenced from: MyCOde.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in MyCOde.so
```

Moreover if i try to load the package in R, i get the following

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2'
ld: library not found for -lquadmath
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [MyCode.so] Error 1
```

Can someone helps me?

Comment: Looks like you switched from GCC to CLang, but your MyCOde.so points back to GCC implementation. Rebuild it with CLang.

Comment: Do you know which compiler do you use?

Comment: When i type R  CMD SHLIB   MyCode.cpp i get clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names......., so i guess is clang

Comment: But your library points out to GCC 4.8.2:

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2'

Rebuild your library with CLang. That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it starts to work I can publish the answer for such a cases.

When you change the compiler and standard libraries - please note that different libraries have different implementation and different standard support. Changing the basement of your system might require total rebuild of your system with the new C++ standard library.

Your libraries are not the exception. So if have the errors in your linker like this:

> warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2'

apply next algorithm:

1. Check whether the directory /usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2 still exists. I bet it is not.
2. Check if you still have the libstdc++ from the missed compiler? Usually if you upgrade the same compiler and the C++ standard library ABI does not change everything should continue to work. If the ABI changed or you switch standard C++ library and compiler - you face the massive system rebuild.
3. Recompile your library and apps with the new C++ standard library and compiler.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the helpful website of:
[thecoatlessprofessor](http://www.thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/rcpp-rcpparmadillo-and-os-x-mavericks-lgfortran-and-lquadmath-error)

Type this into your terminal shell:

```
curl -O http://r.research.att.com/libs/gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2
sudo tar fvxz gfortran-4.8.2-darwin13.tar.bz2 -C /
```

This will create what you need to resume compiling as before.